# Having trouble importing files from the SQL load_extension function

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, discord, discord.py

Context - Trying to run a Discord Bot, My OS is Windows 10, Using Ubuntu to run the Bot, Runs perfectly fine off of Visual Studio Code, Won't run on Ubuntu.

Ubuntu response

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "launcher.py", line 5, in
>
> bot.run(VERSION)   File "/home/ubuntu/MemesDiscordBot/lib/bot/**init**.py", line 90, in run
> self.setup()   File "/home/ubuntu/MemesDiscordBot/lib/bot/**init**.py", line 60, in setup
> self.load_extension(f"lib.cogs.{cog}")   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot
> .py", line 659, in load_extension
> spec = importlib.util.find_spec(name)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/util.py", line 94, in find_spec
> parent = **import**(parent_name, fromlist=['**path**']) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.cogs.'

Area of the code from the IDE that won't load on Ubuntu

```
def setup(self):
    cogs = [path.split("\\")[-1][:-3] for path in glob("./lib/cogs/*.py")]
    for cog in cogs:
        self.load_extension(f"lib.cogs.{cog}")
        print(f" {cog} cog loaded")

    print("setup complete")
```

Image of the code from the IDE

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NChxV.png
```

Comment: Please, copy directly the stack trace instead of posting links or images.

Comment: Will do next time, noted.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66080969/edit) your question and post the code and error message

Comment: Fixed it a few minutes ago.